# When I poll records from multiple partitions from kafka and commit one record on one partition, the rest of records are lost

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I poll records from multiple partitions, and just commit one record, then the rest of records seems to be committed too, for I can't poll them again. And I already set `auto.commit` to `false`, can't figure out why. But if the topic has only one partition, it works fine, the records that I didn't commit on first poll will be re-polled again. Why the result is different when there are more than one partition?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
   InterruptedException {
           initKafkaConsumer();
           do {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
            for (TopicPartition partition : records.partitions()) {

                List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> partitionRecords = records.records(partition);
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : partitionRecords) {
                    LOG.info("partition = {}, offset = {}, value = {}", record.partition(), record.offset(), record.value());
                    consumer.commitSync(
                        Collections.singletonMap(partition, new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset() + 1)));
                    break;
                }
            }


        } while (true);
    }
```

According to @mazaneicha's comment, I re-run the program, and the result seems like I have committed all the records for not breaking out of outter loop, but my log says(I have printed out the record info in code) weird things, like these:

09:37:38.786 [main] INFO org.test.kafka.Consumer - partition = 2, offset = 0, value = this message 2

09:37:38.786 [main] INFO org.test.kafka.Consumer - partition = 2, offset = 10, value = this message 21

09:37:38.786 [main] INFO org.test.kafka.Consumer - partition = 2, offset = 11, value = this message 24

09:37:38.786 [main] INFO org.test.kafka.Consumer - partition = 2, offset = 13, value = this message 30

09:37:38.786 [main] INFO org.test.kafka.Consumer - partition = 2, offset = 14, value = this message 33

You can see from log that some of messages are lost, for the offset is not consecutive. Anyone who have clues of why?

Comment: The way it is written seems like you're reading/committing one record _from every partition_, since you `break` from the inner `for` loop only.

Answer (score 0):

Several record are polled at once ( in one call to poll), so try only polling one record at a time (polling interval can be reduced), and commit that record.
Set "max.poll.records" property of kafka consumer to "1".